# Fetching only one item from rss

Tags: android, rss

I want to show in my Android app, a single item from rss each day. 
Now I dont' want to build a complex rss reader with a listview and so, I just want to get a single item each day, is it possible?
Thanks

Comment: Sure it is. What kind of XML-Parser are you using? If you can put all this in a loop to get all entry's, why should getting only the first be a problem?

Comment: I didn't use any parser yet, can you point me to a good guide?

Answer (score 0):

This is a very general question, but I'll do my best to respond to it. You'll need to do three things: get the xml, parse the xml, and then display it.

For getting the XML I recommend using an [AsyncTaskLoader](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/AsyncTaskLoader.html) and an [HttpUrlConnection](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) to download it.

For parsing the XML you have a few options. You can use a [SAX parser](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/SAXParser.html). This is the way I like to do it. You can checkout this [tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-sax-parser/) on how to use the SAX parser. Or if you prefer to use a DOM parser, you can checkout this [tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/).

Once it's been parsed, you can just set the contents of a TextView to whatever you parsed.

I don't have an example of all this because this is bascially an entire android app. But with what I've given you, you should have enough to get started and build one on your own.

Answer (score 0):

Fetching the feed with http and parsing the xml can be easily done with a third party library.

Here's code that I used to fetch the Picasa featured photos feed, and parse the rss item to extract the title and the content url.

```
public void xml_ajax(){


    String url = "https://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/base/featured?max-results=8";      
    aq.ajax(url, XmlDom.class, this, "picasaCb");

}

public void picasaCb(String url, XmlDom xml, AjaxStatus status){

    showResult(xml, status);        
    if(xml == null) return;

    List<XmlDom> entries = xml.tags("entry");

    List<String> titles = new ArrayList<String>();

    String imageUrl = null;

    for(XmlDom entry: entries){
        titles.add(entry.text("title"));
        imageUrl = entry.tag("content", "type", "image/jpeg").attr("src");

    }

    showTextResult(titles);



}
```

I also blogged about this here
http://blog.androidquery.com/2011/09/simpler-and-easier-xml-parsing-in.html